# Change touch receiver while scrolling a scroll view

Tags: ios, scroll, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer, bottom-sheet

Apps like Apple's maps app or Google maps use scrollable bottom sheet overlays to present additional content. While this behavior is not too difficult to rebuild, I struggle to implement one important feature:

When there is a scroll view embedded inside the bottom sheet, then the user can scroll it to the top but then – instead of bouncing off at the top – the bottom sheet starts scrolling down instead of the table view.

Here's an example video of what I mean:

#### [Example Video:](https://youtu.be/u5hzqGCBaDc)

[image: Bottom Sheet Example]

This is a nice user experience as there is no interruption in the scrolling and it's what I expect as a user: It's as if once the content scroll view has reached its top the gesture receiver is automatically handed over the super scroll view.

---

In order to achieve this behavior, I see three different approaches:

1. I track the content scroll view's `contentOffset` in the scroll view's `scrollViewDidScroll(_:)` delegate method. Then I do

   ```
   if contentScrollView.contentOffset.y < 0 {
       contentScrollView.contentOffset.y = 0
   }
   ```

   to keep the content scroll view from scrolling above the top of its content. Instead, I pass the y distance that it *would* have scrolled to the super scroll view which scrolls the whole bottom sheet.

   2. I find a way to change the receiver of the scrolling (pan) gesture recognizer from the content scroll view to the super scroll view as soon as the content scroll view has scrolled to its top.
   3. I handle everything inside the super scroll view. It asks its content view controller through a delegate protocol if it wants to handle the touches and only if it doesn't (because its content scroll view has reached the top) the super scroll view scrolls by itself.

---

While I have managed to implement the first variant (it's what you see in the video), I'd strongly prefer to use approach 2 or 3. It's a much cleaner way to have the view controller that controls the bottom sheet manage all the scrolling logic without exposing its internals.

Unfortunately, I haven't found a way to somehow split the pan gesture into two components (one that controls the receiver scroll view and one that controls another scroll view)

#### Any ideas on how to achieve this kind of behavior?

Comment: touchesBegan touchesMoved,and touchesEnded would all be called so you could track a starting point of the first touch and if the contentOffset hit the target start moving by the distance of the currentTouch from the point which maxContentOffset. Then if move the other way you could check how much translation has happened and go the other way before allowing the scroll. I do think the scrollview never loses the touch because the scroll indicator is present the entire time. I would like to know this as well and if what I am saying is right or wrong.If it is how the content offset locked so nice?

Answer (score 0):

I am very interested in this question and I hope by providing how I would implement it, it does not stifle an answer that might show how to truly pass around the responder.  The trick I think which I put in the comments is keeping track of the touches.  I forgot about how scrollview gobbles those up but you can use a UIPanGesture.  See if this is close to what you are looking for.  The only case I ran into that might take more thought is using the scroll to dismiss the bottom view. Most of this code is setup to get a working scrollview in the view.  I think property animations might be best to make it interruptible or even my personal fav Facebook Pop animations. To keep it simple I just used UIView animations. Let me know if this solves what you are looking for. **The code is below and here is the result**
[image: sogif]. The scrollview remains scrollable and active. I animate the frames but updating constraints could work as well.

```
import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController{
        //setup
        var items : [Int] = []
        lazy var tableView : UITableView = {
            let tv = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: topViewHeight, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height))
            tv.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth,.flexibleHeight]
            tv.delegate = self
            tv.dataSource = self
            tv.layer.cornerRadius = 4
            return tv
        }()

        lazy var topView : UIView = {
            let v = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: topViewHeight))
            v.backgroundColor = .green
            v.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth,.flexibleHeight]
            return v
        }()

        let cellIdentifier = "ourCell"



        //for animation
        var isAnimating = false
        var lastOffset : CGPoint = .zero
        var startingTouch : CGPoint?
        let topViewHeight : CGFloat = 500
        var isShowing : Bool = false
        let maxCollapse : CGFloat = 50




        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            for x in 0...100{
                items.append(x)
            }
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
            self.view.addSubview(topView)
            self.view.addSubview(tableView)
            self.tableView.reloadData()

            let pan = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(moveFunction(pan:)))
            pan.delegate = self
            self.view.addGestureRecognizer(pan)
        }

        @objc func moveFunction(pan:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
            let point:CGPoint = pan.location(in: self.view)
            switch pan.state {
            case .began:
                startingTouch = point
                break
            case .changed:
                  processMove(touchPoint:point.y)
                break
            default:
                processEnding(currentPointY: point.y)
                break
            }
        }

    }

    extension ViewController : UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

        func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            return 1
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return items.count
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            var cell : UITableViewCell!
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
            if cell == nil {
                cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
            }
            cell.textLabel?.text = "\(items[indexPath.row])"
            return cell
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
            return 30
        }
    }

    extension ViewController : UIScrollViewDelegate{
        func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
            if isAnimating == true{
                scrollView.contentOffset = lastOffset
                return
            }
            lastOffset = scrollView.contentOffset
        }
    }

    extension ViewController : UIGestureRecognizerDelegate{
        func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
            return true
        }
    }

    extension ViewController{
        func processMove(touchPoint:CGFloat){
            if let start = startingTouch{
                if touchPoint <= topViewHeight && start.y > topViewHeight{
                    isAnimating = true
                    tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y:touchPoint, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)
                    return
                }else if touchPoint >= self.maxCollapse && isShowing == true && start.y < self.maxCollapse{
                    isAnimating = true
                    tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y:touchPoint, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)
                    return
                }else if isShowing == true && self.tableView.contentOffset.y <= 0{
                    //this is the only one i am slightly unsure about
                    isAnimating = true
                    tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y:touchPoint, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)
                    return
                }
            }
            self.isAnimating = false
        }

        func processEnding(currentPointY:CGFloat){
            startingTouch = nil

            if isAnimating{
                if currentPointY < topViewHeight/2{
                    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.9, initialSpringVelocity: 0.0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
                        self.tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y:self.maxCollapse, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)
                    }) { (finished) in
                        self.isShowing = true
                    }
                }else{
                    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.9, initialSpringVelocity: 0.0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
                        self.tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y:self.topViewHeight, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)
                    }) { (finished) in
                        self.isShowing = false

                    }
                }
            }
            self.isAnimating = false
        }
    }
```